# How to write tests for cpp functions in R package?

Tags: r, unit-testing, rcpp

To speed some functions in R package, I have re-coded them in cpp functions using Rcpp and successfully embedded those cpp functions into this package. The next step is to test if the cpp functions can output the same results as  the original functions in R. So writing tests is necessary.

However, I was stuck on this step. I have read some links
[Testing, R package by Hadley Wickham](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html#test-tests)

and [CRAN:testthat, page 11](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/testthat.pdf#page=10).

What I have done is that I run `devtools::use_testthat()`to create a tests/testthat directory. Then, run `use_catch(dir = getwd())`to add a test file tests/testthat/test-cpp.R. At this point, I think `expect_cpp_tests_pass()` might work but was just stuck on it. If I have the original function called `add_inflow` and `add_inflow_Cpp`. How can I test if these two functions are equal?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, *"At this point, I think [...] but was just stuck on it"* -- did encounter errors or something?

Comment: Please post a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @nrussell There was no error at all, it was just meaning that I didn't know how to keep going, is there any intuition that can help me continue?

Comment: Well, would you consider documentation written by someone other than Hadley?  Or did it occur to you to look at existing tests in the 864 CRAN packages using Rcpp?

Comment: IIUC, the question here is specifically about how to use the bundled Catch library in conjunction with `testthat`, which is a relatively new feature and not yet used by many packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for `?use_catch` attempts to describe exactly how the testing infrastructure for `testthat` works here, so I'll just copy that as an answer:

> Calling use_catch() will:
>
> 1. Create a file src/test-runner.cpp, which ensures that the testthat
>      package will understand how to run your package's unit tests,
> 2. Create an example test file src/test-example.cpp, which showcases how
>      you might use Catch to write a unit test, and
> 3. Add a test file tests/testthat/test-cpp.R, which ensures that testthat
>      will run your compiled tests during invocations of devtools::test() or
>      R CMD check.
>
> C++ unit tests can be added to C++ source files within the src/
>   directory of your package, with a format similar to R code tested with
>   testthat.
>
> When your package is compiled, unit tests alongside a harness for running these tests will be
>   compiled into your R package, with the C entry point
>   run_testthat_tests(). testthat will use that entry point to run your
>   unit tests when detected.

In short, if you want to write your own C++ unit tests using Catch, you can follow the example of the auto-generated `test-example.cpp` file. `testthat` will automatically run your tests, and report failures during the regular `devtools::test()` process.

Note that the use of Catch is specifically for writing unit tests at the C++ level. If you want to write R test code, then Catch won't be relevant for your use case.

---

One package you might look at as motivation is the [icd](https://github.com/jackwasey/icd) package -- see [this file](https://github.com/jackwasey/icd/blob/master/src/test-cpp.cpp) for one example of how you might write Catch unit tests with the `testthat` wrappers.